# Unity get_dataPath not allowed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem use Application.dataPath

The Error:
UnityException: get_dataPath is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'SaveAndLoadMenu' on game object 'Save And Load Menu'.
See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
FilePaths..cctor () (at Assets/_MAIN/Scripts/Core/IO/FilePaths.cs:8)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'FilePaths' threw an exception.

The Error indicate FilePaths.cs  at
public static readonly string root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/"; this line

And Menupage.cs inherited MonoBehaviour

```
public class FilePaths
{
    private const string HOME_DIRECTORY_SYMBOL = "~/";

    
*    public static readonly string root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/";* // Error 


    //Runtime Path
    public static readonly string gameSaves = $"{runtimePath}Save Files/";


    public static readonly string resources_font = "Fonts/";
    public static readonly string resources_graphics = "Graphics/";
    public static readonly string resources_backgroundImages = $"{resources_graphics}BG/";
    public static readonly string resources_backgroundVideos = $"{resources_graphics}BG Videos/";
    public static readonly string resources_blendTextures = $"{resources_graphics}Transition Effects/";

    public static readonly string resources_audio = "Audio/";
    public static readonly string resources_sfx = $"{resources_audio}SFX/";
    public static readonly string resources_voices = $"{resources_audio}Voices/";
    public static readonly string resources_bgm = $"{resources_audio}BGM/";
    public static readonly string resources_ambience = $"{resources_audio}Ambience/";

    public static readonly string resources_dialogueFiles = $"Dialogue Files/";

    public static string GetPathToResource(string defaultPath, string resourceName)
    {
        if(resourceName.StartsWith(HOME_DIRECTORY_SYMBOL))
        {
            return resourceName.Substring(HOME_DIRECTORY_SYMBOL.Length);
        }

        return defaultPath + resourceName;
    }


    public static string runtimePath
    {
        get
        {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
                return "Assets/appdata/";
            #else
                return Application.persistentDataPath + "/appdata/";
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SaveAndLoadMenu : MenuPage
{
    public static SaveAndLoadMenu Instance {get; private set;}

    const int MAX_FILES = 99;
    string savePath = FilePaths.gameSaves;
    int currentPage = 1;
    bool loadedFilesForFirstTime = false;

    public enum MenuFunction {save, load}
    public MenuFunction menuFunction = MenuFunction.save;

    public SaveLoadSlot[] saveSlots;
    int slotsPerPage => saveSlots.Length;

    public Texture emptyFileImage;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public override void Open()
    {
        base.Open();

        if(!loadedFilesForFirstTime)
            PopulateSaveSlotsForPage(currentPage);
    }

    void PopulateSaveSlotsForPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        int startingFile = ((currentPage - 1) * slotsPerPage) + 1;
        int endingFile = startingFile + slotsPerPage -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < slotsPerPage; i++)
        {
            int fileNum = startingFile + i;
            SaveLoadSlot slot = saveSlots[i];

            if(fileNum < MAX_FILES)
            {
                slot.root.SetActive(true);
                string filePath = $"{FilePaths.gameSaves}{fileNum}{VNGameSave.FILE_TYPE}";
                slot.fileNumber = fileNum;
                slot.filePath = filePath;
                slot.PopulateDetails(menuFunction);
            }
            else
            {
                slot.root.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was tried

```
public static string Root { get; private set; }

private void Awake()
{
    Root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/";
}
```

Comment: Do you still have the same error after trying?

Comment: @shingo  yeah it still error

Comment: @shingo Do you mean delete that line and add
    public static string Root { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/";
    }

right?
i will try it thank you for reply

Comment: ... My first question is: 
Do you still have the **same** error after trying? If it changed, you need to show the new error instead of the one before trying.

Comment: @shingo I solved this problem! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you you can not use `Application.dataPath` at field initialization

```
public static readonly string root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/";
```

what you can do though is e.g. using

```
public static string root { get; private set ;}

[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.SubsystemRegistration)]
private static void Init()
{
    root = $"{Application.dataPath}/gameData/";
}
```

See [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html)